# Moving files from parent folder to subfolders

Tags: windows, batch

I am trying to fix the following problem through a batch file.

`test` is a parent folder, which contains further subfolders `test1`, `test2`, `test3`. All these subfolders `test1`, `test2`, `test3` contain some `.docx` files and a further subfolder archive.

- Look for existing `.docx` files in subfolders `test1`, `test2`, `test3`.
- Copy them to a desired folder named `destination`.

The following code works fine for the first part of problem:

```
for /R "C:\test" %%f in (*.docx) do xcopy %%f "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\destination\"  /exclude:c:\test\not_required.txt
```

Now I want to move the `.docx` files from subfolders `test1`, `test2`, `test3` to their respective subfolder archive. Till now I could only built the following code for the second part of my problem.

```
for /d /r "c:\test" %%a in (*) do (
if /i "%%~nxa"=="archiv" set "folderpath=%%a"
move "C:\test\test1\test1.docx" "%folderpath%" 
)
```

As you can see I have given for source a static file move `C:\test\test1\test1.docx`. I am not sure how to use more variables inside loops and Unfortunately it is not working as desired. A piece of advice from some experts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to move the files to the archive directory before or after the copy?

Comment: From my understanding I have to give a specific path as a destination for move command. Does it works with wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that the `For /R` will also dive into the archive folders so this has to be avoided.

If your folder structure has no varying depth you can use a for /d with a wildcard to get only direct subfolders of `C:\test`

With this sample situation:

```
> tree /F
C:\
├───Test
│   ├───test1
│   │   │   Example_8192.docx
│   │   │   Example_32457.docx
│   │   │
│   │   └───archive
│   ├───test2
│   │   │   Example_14218.docx
│   │   │   Example_20916.docx
│   │   │
│   │   └───archive
│   └───test3
│       │   Example_12174.docx
│       │   Example_9168.docx
│       │
│       └───archive
└───Users
    └───UserName
        └───Desktop
            └───Destination
```

This batch using for [variable modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) :

```
:: C:\Copy+Archive.cmd
@Echo off
For /D %%D in ("C:\test\*") do (
    Echo Processing %%D
    For %%F in ("%%~fD\*.docx") do (
        Echo Copying "%%~fF" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Destination\"
        xcopy "%%~fF" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Destination\" >Nul && (
        Echo Moving  "%%~fF" "%%~dpFarchive\"
        Move  "%%~fF" "%%~dpFarchive\" >Nul
        )
    )
)
```

will produce this result

```
> tree /f
C:\
│   Copy+Archive.cmd
│
├───Test
│   ├───test1
│   │   └───archive
│   │           Example_8192.docx
│   │           Example_32457.docx
│   │
│   ├───test2
│   │   └───archive
│   │           Example_14218.docx
│   │           Example_20916.docx
│   │
│   └───test3
│       └───archive
│               Example_12174.docx
│               Example_9168.docx
│
└───Users
    └───UserName
        └───Desktop
            └───Destination
                    Example_8192.docx
                    Example_32457.docx
                    Example_14218.docx
                    Example_20916.docx
                    Example_12174.docx
                    Example_9168.docx
```